# Step by step installation of Java 7 JDK on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, java

I have fresh mac and don't want to break anything so here's kind of silly question from someone who calls himself java developer.

I've installed newest JDK from Oracle 1.7.10 and I can confirm that it was installed successfully by running `java -version` in console. However I cannot run IntelliJ application which I've also installed because window pops up asking me:
"To open “IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE,” you need a Java runtime. Would you like to install one now?"

It is kind of nasty because if I agree to install it then from what I know it will install some Mac JRE version 6 something and this is rather useless for me - that's why I didn't click it.

I've exported path `export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home"` but it didn't help and I still cannot run IntelliJ via Applications.

So what should I do? I'm not in rush for setting up this machine so I'd rather ask and wait than install some useless jre.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this popup doesn't install apple's JRE but installs some update and after that update everything works fine.